# iOS 3rd Party Framework assure no network connections

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks

In a project we are currently working on we need to rely on a precompiled 3rd party framework. 
Is there any way to assure that it is not able to open up a network connection and send out confidential data?

**Edit:**

To make this a little clearer: It does not have to be at runtime. A static check is fine. I was more thinking something along the lines of: Is there a library that everyone who wants to use network has to link against?

Comment: You can only able to check it when you have access of .m files. There is no other option.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way to accomplish what you want. Check [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/) out. Install `mitmproxy` on your mac windows or whatever, install your app on the device, launch `mitmproxy` on the terminal, make your computer's IP a proxy on the device, install https certificate as described on `mitmproxy` docs, launch you app, and enjoy! `mitmproxy` can show all outgoing connections from your app. Good luck!

**EDIT**

Starting from iOS 9, you can set trusted hosts in the app `Info.plist` under `App Transport Security Settings` key. More info about it you can find [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33). Hope this was helpful.

Comment: This can only verify that the framework makes no network calls whilst you are testing it. This will not verify that the framework won't make network calls ever.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it is possible to ensure an app never makes a network call.

As Fahri Azimov suggests, you could test whether the 3rd party framework makes network calls by funnelling all traffic from test devices through a proxy. You can do this locally on you Mac using the iOS Simulator and [Little Snitch.](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) But this cannot ensure that the framework will Never make a network call.

A work-around to ensure no your app performs no networking could be to use [NSURLProtocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLProtocol_Class/) to intercept any network calls and return errors. You could look at the [OHHTTPStubs framework](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHHTTPStubs) for inspiration. But, again, this is limited as it will only catch NSURLConnection / NSURLSession networking calls, it won't intercept low-level networking operations which the framework could make.